# How can I alter this code so that the output is flipped?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am making this code that displays a series of asterisks in rows that get smaller by one each time you go down a row. It's supposed to start at 10 and stop at 1 on the very bottom row but for some reason my code starts with 1 at the top and grows bigger as it goes down. I was wondering how I could go about flipping the output so that it looks like the example. Thanks in advance

Example:

```
**********  
*********  
******** 
******* 
****** 
***** 
**** 
***  
**  
*
```

My code:

```
public class RowsOfAsterisks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you used a code block, the asterisks would have shown

Answer (score 3):

You can create another method in order to avoid two for statment

Check if it can help you:

```
public class RowsOfAsterisks
{
    public static String repeat(String str, int times)
    {
      return new String(new char[times]).replace("\0", str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
      {
        System.out.println(repeat("*", i));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the method is static, it can be called directly; if that's what you meant Robert.

Comment: I meant method... Thanks for the correction guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to start the outer loop from `10` to achieve this.

I hope the below code helps you:

```
public class RowsOfAsterisks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
int rows = 10;

int columns = 10;




for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; int j < columns; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    --columns;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track you just need to fix up the nested loop like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 11; x > i; x--)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```